# Dynamically adding up column variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I need help in dynamically adding up variables and evaluating them inside a dplyr pipe.

For example I have a dataset and I have to go:

```
test_variable_construction %>%
  mutate(Total_Utilisation_Sum_3m = Total_Utilisation+Lag1_Total_Utilisation+Lag2_Total_Utilisation)
```

and

```
test_variable_construction %>%
  mutate(Total_Utilisation_Sum_6m = Total_Utilisation + Lag1_Total_Utilisation + Lag2_Total_Utilisation + Lag3_Total_Utilisation + Lag4_Total_Utilisation + Lag5_Total_Utilisation)
```

so I want to create a string as such:

```
paste(iterates,collapse="+")
```

`"Total_Utilisation+Lag1_Total_Utilisation+Lag2_Total_Utilisation"`

and pass this into the dplyr pipe:

```
test_variable_construction %>%
mutate(Total_Utilisation_Sum_3m := eval(!!paste(iterates,collapse="+"))
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't work -- does anyone know the right syntax to for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option to achieve your desired result would be to use `rowwise` like so:

```r
library(dplyr)

test_df <- data.frame(Total = 1:5)
test_df[paste0("Lag", 1:2, "_Total")] <- lapply(1:2, function(x) 1:5)

iterates <- c("Total", paste0("Lag", 1:2, "_Total"))

test_df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(Total_Sum_3m = sum(c_across(all_of(iterates)))) %>% 
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 5 × 4
#>   Total Lag1_Total Lag2_Total Total_Sum_3m
#>   <int>      <int>      <int>        <int>
#> 1     1          1          1            3
#> 2     2          2          2            6
#> 3     3          3          3            9
#> 4     4          4          4           12
#> 5     5          5          5           15
```

Or using `rowSums` you could do:

```
test_df %>% 
  mutate(Total_Sum_3m = rowSums(.[iterates]))
#>   Total Lag1_Total Lag2_Total Total_Sum_3m
#> 1     1          1          1            3
#> 2     2          2          2            6
#> 3     3          3          3            9
#> 4     4          4          4           12
#> 5     5          5          5           15
```

Note: Using `eval` you could achieve your result via

```
test_df %>%
  mutate(Total_Sum_3m = eval(parse(text = paste(iterates, collapse = "+"))))
```

However, in general using `eval(parse = ...` is not recommended. See e.g. [this post](https://www.examplefiles.net/cs/12831) for a collection of reasons to avoid `eval(parse = ...`.

Comment: Thank you so much stefan :)  I am using sparklyr package, so the dataframe is a spark dataframe.  So unfortunately, it doesn't have rowise functionality.  It helped a lot when you provided the eval command as well, but will look into to see why its not best to use.

Answer (score 0):

So the parse_expr from rlang worked for me.

For example, I had to go:

```
test_variable_construction %>%
mutate(Total_Utilisation_Sum_3m = !!parse_expr(paste(iterates), collapse = " + "))
```